# Why can't Azure find IISConfigurator.exe in my cspkg?

Tags: azure, azure-web-roles

I am using the Azure 2.5 SDK to upload a cspkg + cscfg to create a new web role deployment in Azure. When I do, I see the following error with status **BadRequest**.

> {"BadRequest : The file provided is not a valid service package. Detailed error code: {0} Invalid application runtime - a runtime component is missing:/base/x64/IISConfigurator.exe."}

Where {0} is the role/project name.

*However*, when I inspect the contents of my cspkg file, the base/x64 directory DOES contain IISConfigurator.exe.

I also notice that the RoleModel.xml file has been modified by packaging to contain an IISConfigurator.exe task as follows:

```
<RoleModel xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="CacheExtension" version="2.5.6496.10" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ServiceHosting/2008/10/ServiceDefinition">
  <Startup>
    <Task commandLine="IISConfigurator.exe" executionContext="elevated" relativePath="base\x64">
      <Environment>
        <Variable name="_IISCONFIGURATOR_SETUP_URL_REWRITE_" value="true" />
        <Variable name="_IISCONFIGURATOR_CLEAN_SERVER_ONSTARTUP_" value="true" />
        <Variable name="RdModuleName" value="IISConfigurator" />
      </Environment>
    </Task>
```

So my question is: What is the real cause of this error message?

Additional possible clues:
My RoleModel.xml in the cspkg also contains:

```
<Property name="TargetFrameworkVersion" value="v4.5.1" />
<Property name="RoleType" value="Web" />
<Property name="Configuration" value="Debug" />
<Property name="Platform" value="AnyCPU" />
<Property name="SetConfiguration" value="Configuration=Debug" />
<Property name="SetPlatform" value="Platform=AnyCPU" />
<Property name="RoleTargetFramework" value="v4.5.1" />
<Property name="TargetRuntimeVersion" value="v4.0" />
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tim, we have seen this issue only twice, and it was with developers who had upgraded to SDK 2.5.1.  We were never able to reproduce the problem and we didn't find the root cause before those developers uninstalled the Azure SDK and reinstalled SDK 2.5 which caused the issue to go away.

Can you try uninstalling and reinstalling the Azure SDK?  You could also try SDK 2.6 which was just released.

Comment: It seems like I had a preview version of the SDK: I couldn't uninstall MicrosoftAzureTools.VS120.exe by running because it says I have a different version install, but I could uninstall it from the control panel. I see in control panel in fact I have two 'Azure Authoring Tools' (2.5.6469.10 and 2.5.6499.15) installed. I uninstalled them both. Then I installed MicrosoftAzureAuthoringTools-x64.msi which succeeded. Installing MicrosoftAzureTools.VS120.exe was still failing. Then I uninstalled from control panel 'Microsoft.Azure.Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 - v2.5' (2.5.30319.1603).

Comment: Then finally, I became able to run MicrosoftAzureTools.VS120.exe to install the non-preview 2.5 tools. [BTW I don't think I can take a dependency on Azure 2.6 runtime due to assembly dependencies of my project. I assume 2.6 SDK doesn't targeting 2.5 azure runtime?]

Comment: The CSPKG generated after I did this software maintenance seems identical, except for the various Azure DLLS in the package - and their hashes in the .csman. Anyhow that seemed to fix it!

Comment: Glad to hear it Tim, thanks for the update.  2.6 doesn't use the 2.5 runtime, but you should be able to create a binding redirect in your config file to redirect 2.5 to 2.6.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue using the Azure 2.9 SDK.
I started looking in control panel and was seeing what appeared to be some double installs.
I uninstalled all 2.9 Azure components from my PC, and reinstalled the required ones. Then it all worked for me.