# azure cloud service node js "not a valid service package"

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-web-roles, azure-cloud-services

I have a cloud service in azure with two .NET worker roles and i want to add a Node JS webrole.
I have installed the Node.JS tools for visual studio which creates templates from which should allow node apps to be deployed as a web role.

Packaging of the service goes smoothly, but after publishing the cloud service via visual studio the following error message is shown:

```
The file provided is not a valid service package. Detailed error code: presentation Invalid application runtime - a runtime component is missing:/base/x64/WaIISHost.exe.
```

But when I look in the package file for the cloud service using an archiving tool and go to /base/x64/, the exe "WaIISHost.exe" is there.

I am quite stuck at the moment. There seem to be few other people that have this issue and I have already reinstalled the Azure SDK as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29979596/why-cant-azure-find-iisconfigurator-exe-in-my-cspkg)  and I am using the latest version (2.9.1).

Comment: I created a test cloud service which contains .Net worker role and a nodejs web role. They are all added via VS template. And the scenario worked fine on Azure Cloud Service. Do you have any custom configurations in your cloud service project?

Comment: Not really. The worker roles are connected to each other using internal endpoints, but that has not been an issue before. The node app is just a placeholder until I can successfully publish it. It is the standard hello world app at the moment.

Comment: I have the same problem. But I change two things in the configuration so that long path names are avoided: (1) rename the web role to a short name. (2) modified the *.ccproj file as suggested here http://stackoverflow.com/a/18749595/2272514

Comment: The question you linked is about the building process. My application "builds" correctly and I receive the error when uploading the package to azure. I did encounter the path issue, but I just moved the entire project to the root of the drive to work around it.